# Why does my C program keep crashing in CMD

Tags: c

Here is my program:

I'm new to coding, as much as I can tell, there is no problem with this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int X;
  int Y;
  int S = X + Y;
  int D = X - Y;
  double M = X / Y;

  printf("Entrer X:");
  scanf("%d", X);
  printf("Entrer Y:");
  scanf("%d", Y);

  printf("%f", M);



}
```

Comment: Because you're using `X` and `Y` before initializing them.

Comment: `&`ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: @Asfhraf Use `&` while doing scanf, `scanf("%d", &Y);` and perform operations on X and Y after scanf, so that you have the value stored in.

Comment: Order matters, calculations are not redone in retrospect. The values of `X` and `Y` are *indeterminate* (and could be seen as random or garbage) when you use them in your calculations. It's not the cause of the crash though,

Comment: If you compile your code with warnings enabled, you'll see at least some of the mistakes made here.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli   I completely forgot about it xD

Answer (score 1):

You seem a bit confused about what assignment means.

When you do this

```
int S = X + Y;
```

you're actually making that calculation, you're not saying "when the program encounters `S` later it should carry out the calculation".

You need to use values when you actually have them.

Also, `scanf` expects the address of a variable, not the variable itself (so `&X`, not `X`).

So:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int X;
  int Y;


  printf("Entrer X:");
  scanf("%d", &X);
  printf("Entrer Y:");
  scanf("%d", &Y);

  double M = X / Y;
  printf("%f", M);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables X and Y are not initialized and have indeterminate values.

Arguments of these calls must be pointers

```
  scanf("%d", X);
  scanf("%d", Y);
```

that is

```
  scanf("%d", &X);
  scanf("%d", &Y);
```

And it seems you at first need to enter values for the variables X and Y and only after that use them in expressions.

Also in this statement

```
  double M = X / Y;
```

in the right hand side of the assignment there is used the integer arithmetic. You should write

```
  double M = ( double )X / Y;
```

Answer (score 0):

`X` and `Y` aren't initialized when you attempt to use them. Specifically, while you should never depend on this **undefined behavior**, many compilers will initialize an `int` with a `0`, so when you calculate `M`, your program probably crashes because of the zero-division.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable warnings and treat warnings as errors, you will get output like this:

```sh
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -o scratch main.c
main.c:12:17: error: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Werror,-Wformat]
    scanf("%d", X);
           ~~   ^
main.c:14:17: error: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Werror,-Wformat]
    scanf("%d", Y);
           ~~   ^
main.c:7:9: error: unused variable 'S' [-Werror,-Wunused-variable]
    int S = X + Y;
        ^
main.c:8:9: error: unused variable 'D' [-Werror,-Wunused-variable]
    int D = X - Y;
        ^
main.c:7:13: error: variable 'X' is uninitialized when used here [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]
    int S = X + Y;
            ^
main.c:5:10: note: initialize the variable 'X' to silence this warning
    int X;
         ^
          = 0
main.c:7:17: error: variable 'Y' is uninitialized when used here [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]
    int S = X + Y;
                ^
main.c:6:10: note: initialize the variable 'Y' to silence this warning
    int Y;
         ^
          = 0
6 errors generated.
```

This should get you started down the path to fixing your problem.